# Facebook ID properly read by SQL but not by PHP?

Tags: php, sql, facebook, encryption

On a logged in portion of my site I am trying to allow the user to write some info about themselves. I have a functional, but non-secure login/registration page that I am trying to replace with a simple "log in with facebook" button.

The issue is, once the user logs in with facebook, they can update the info, but they can't access it. The $uid variable contains their unique facebook user ID, the SQL function reads it properly and inserts it into the database, but all the other PHP functions read it as an entirely different number. Is the SQL decoding $uid while the PHP echoes an encrypted version?

The following puts a new piece of info in under the correct facebook ID, then echoes an incorrect facebook ID:

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO Users (ID, Date, Category, Info)
VALUES
($uid, '$myTime', '$category','$info')";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Info Saved<br>";

echo " session: " . $_SESSION['uid'] . " PHP uid: " . $uid . " cookie: " . $_COOKIE['uid'];
```

I can tell the SQL function is working properly because the true ID is stored next to the info in the database and the data is displayed when the user logs in with the non-secure form.

Output:

```
 Info Saved
 session: 100005003165914 PHP uid: 100005003165914 cookie: 100005003165914
```

This happens when I log in with the unsecure form:

```
 Info Saved
 session: 2147483647 PHP uid: 2147483647 cookie: 2147483647
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code it's not clear what's the difference between the secure and the non-secure form, but I suspect that at some point `$_SESSION['uid']` is read back from the database and that the `ID` column is only am INT, which cannot store 100005003165914 but a maximum of 2147483647 - which happens to be exactly the value you get.

Comment: I agree with @AndreKR, can you share the relevant database schema?  You may try adding a `facebook_id` field of type `bigint` or `numeric` to handle the users's facebook account and just generate your own `id` field consistently across users regardless of whether they use facebook to login.    Actually check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743023/how-to-handle-facebooks-new-uid-sizes).  They suggest using `varchar` to handle the Facebook IDs.

Comment: @AndreKR You pretty much nailed it. I suspected it could be something like that, but I just adjusted the max size of the int instead of changing the variable type. I changed it to Big Int and the problem is solved! Its funny because the FB account I made to test the site is so much younger than my real account that the ID number is huge. This explains why my original worked with the "log in w/facebook" feature while the new one didn't! I'll try it with varchar too! Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: I got stuck with the same problem. But it didnt work even with `BigInt ` in my case. Previously i was using `varchar`

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between non-secure form and unsecure form? Both sounds similar to me.
Also try this answer: [Get User Id from Facebook in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948668/get-user-id-from-facebook-in-php)